# After upgrading min iOS SDK hitting error for react-native-firebase package

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, podfile

Hitting this error after updating min sdk in podfile from **platform :ios, '9.0'** to **platform :ios, '10.3'**.

> ***xxx/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/analytics/RNFirebaseAnalytics.m:20:19: No known class method for selector 'setScreenName:screenClass:'***

Version info:

```
"react-native-firebase": "5.5.6",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
```

No errors after reverting to **platform :ios, '9.0'**

Any ideas why?